# Authentication with Apple Developer Portal failed EAS ios build

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, eas

I am in the process of creating a React Native app. Is it possible to build a development build for IOS without a paid Apple Developer account? I would like to be able to test my app without paying the fee for a true Apple Developer account, with intentions of paying once I am ready to release. Is this possible, or are there any workarounds that I could use to test my app with custom plugins on IOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

without apple developer account you can build for simulator only, add below "simulator":true on your eas.json
build new development profile

```
{
    "build": {
      "preview": {
        "ios": {
          "simulator": true
        }
      },
      "developmentios": { "developmentClient": true, "distribution": "internal", "ios": { "simulator": true } },
      "production": {}
    }
  }
```

build command

```
eas build --profile developmentios --platform ios
```

reference: https://docs.expo.dev/build-reference/simulators/